# Setting the Attached Property during DataContextChanged event erases the binding content at ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I found that if I set the the Attached Property during `DataContextChanged` event, then the binding content at the ViewModel will be erased.

Here is the code sample:

`App.xaml`

```
<Application x:Class="DataContextChanged.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataContextChanged"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

`ResourceDitionary.xaml`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SubControlVM}">
    <local:SubControl
       local:AttachedBehaviors.Exporter="{Binding ExtraProperty, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
        />
</DataTemplate>
```

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="DataContextChanged.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataContextChanged"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SubControlVM}" />
</Window>
```

`SubControl.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataContextChanged.SubControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataContextChanged"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Label Content="{Binding ExtraProperty}" Background="AliceBlue"/>
</UserControl>
```

`SubControl.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class SubControl : UserControl
{
    public SubControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
    }

    private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AttachedBehaviors.SetExporter(this, 420);  //setting this erases the VM.ExtraProperty and makes it 0
        // var vm = e.NewValue as SubControlVM; //neither this works
        // if(vm!=null)
        //{
        //    vm.ExtraProperty = 420;
        //  }
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //AttachedBehaviors.SetExporter(this, 42);  //setting this at onLoaded Event updates the VM.ExtraProperty successfully to 42.
    }
}
```

`SubControlVM`

```
public class SubControlVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _extraProperty;
    public double ExtraProperty
    {
        get { return _extraProperty; }
        set
        {
            _extraProperty = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ExtraProperty)));

        }
    }

    public SubControlVM()
    {
        ExtraProperty = 1;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

`MainWindowVM`

```
public class MainWindowVM:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SubControlVM _subControlVM;
    public SubControlVM SubControlVM
    {
        get { return _subControlVM; }
        set
        {
            _subControlVM = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SubControlVM)));

        }
    }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        SubControlVM = new SubControlVM();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

`AttachedBehavior.cs`

```
public static class AttachedBehaviors
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExporterProperty =
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Exporter", typeof(double), typeof(AttachedBehaviors));

    public static double GetExporter(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(ExporterProperty);
    }

    public static void SetExporter(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {

        obj.SetValue(ExporterProperty, value);
    }
}
```

As noted above, if the `AttachedBehaviors.SetExporter(this, 42)` is done inside the `OnLoaded` event, then the `VM.ExtraProperty` is updated successfully, but if it is done inside the DataContextChanged event, then `VM.ExtraProperty` will be set to 0.

Even if I try to set the `VM.ExtraProperty` directly inside the `DataContextChanged` event, it will also get reset back to default value (0).

Why is this so? If I really have to set the `VM.ExtraProperty` during the `DataContextChanged` time and not `OnLoaded` time, then how can I make it to work?

Comment: sorry for trying to help, and thanks for the downvote, i delete my project again, good luck

Comment: is the ExporterProperty always reset to 0 after the DataContextChanged no matter what value was there before?

Comment: what you see in the callstack when the value is being set to the zero?

Comment: @chviLadislav, as long as if I set the attached property during `DataContextChanged`, then the VM value will be reset to 0.

Comment: It seems that somehow WPF resets the `ExtraProperty` to 0 out of nowhere

Comment: What is the relationship between `SubControlVM.ExtraProperty` and `AttachedBehaviors.Exporter`? Is there any Binding? Why is `App.xaml` relevant?

Comment: @Clemens, I've updated the question. Now it should be clear

Comment: I have observed in a similar scenario (DataContext changed, properties changed to some magic values - probably cached values) that the callstack contained a wpf call InvalidateProperty. I'm suspicious that the datacontext change leads to property invalidation, but I don't know any details how this works, I had to just ignore the changes when datacontext was null.. Do you have this call in your callstack?

Comment: Just a note, you don't actually need an attached property. If you turn Exporter into a regular dependency property of SubControl, the behavior is still the same.